# How to resolve error :Left side ($point) of '>=' operation has null value

Tags: java, velocity

The problem I am facing is that occasionally Resourcenotfound/unable to
parse file error comes on the velocity pages.

The following error is shown in the server logs before the logging of
resourcenotfound exception:

Left side ($point) of '>=' operation has null value. Operation not possible.

Is something related to the velocity engine here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Claude mentioned, the problem is with a `null` value.

T avoid it, you can check whether `$points` is null first, and then do whatever you want to...

Using `#if ($!points ...)` is better approach here...

## Edit

Further explaining it, you code may look like this:

```
## Check whether the object represented by $points is null or not

#if ($!points)

    ## If $points exists, then perform your checks and calculations.

    #if ($points ...)
        ## Your business action
    #end

#end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is Velocity which emits the error.
Somewhere in your template, you have something like:

```
#if( $point >= ..... )
```

where $point is null. It is just a warning, but it may brake further dynamic resource name calculation or the like.